# MCP4011 - Exposed pad - connect to GND?

Tags: pcb-design, digital-potentiometer, pad

I'm planning to use an MCP4011-xxx/MC (DFN version).

This package has an exposed PAD. But nowhere in the datasheet, I can find the information if this exposed PAD should remain NC or tied to GND/VSS.

I used for other components DFN packages before and it was always mentioned, how the exposed PAD should be connected.

How the pad should be connected and where do I find this information?
Can I assume that when it's not mentioned the default is connected to GND?

[Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001978D.pdf)

[Microchip website](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP4011#additional-features)

Comment: My advice is to ask Microchip directly. I don't see any reference to it in the datasheet either, but exposed pads are not usually left unconnected, as that would limit their usefulness for power dissipation.

Comment: The centre pad is listed as optional, so it would be safest to omit it, or leave it N/C. I have trashed a board iteration by connecting a pad to GND that should have gone to 'most negative' supply. However, this device is single supply rather than dual, so you might assume that it's OK to connect to ground. Do you need it for thermal dissipation?

Comment: Although I agree with Hearth the **best is to ask Microchip self**, other Volatile Digital Potentiometer datasheets (e.g. [MCP454X](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22107B.pdf) and [MCP453X](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22096b.pdf) ) suggest: 

`The DFN and QFN packages have a contact on the bottom of the package. This contact is conductively connected to the die substrate, and therefore should be unconnected or connected to the same ground as the device’s VSS pin.`

Comment: @Neil_UK no, thermal dissipation is not an issue

Comment: then leave it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw this question is still open.

1. in my project I left the center pad unconnected and it works fine.
2. I just took 1 part and measured -> the center pad is not connected to GND internally